# Cannot find out module Data.Colour

Tags: haskell

I cannot import module Data.Colour, and the error as follow:

Could not find module `Data.Colour'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Hayoo! search](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html#0%3aData.Colour) reveals that this module lives in the [colour](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/colour) package, which you presumably don't have installed. To install it, run `cabal update` followed by `cabal install colour`.

Comment: I import a module Random ("import Random"), but still have an error like that Could not find module `Random'
    It is a member of the hidden package `haskell98-2.0.0.1'.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for. Even, I've tried install all module concerned with Random

Comment: @chipbk10: Change it to import `System.Random`.

Comment: so, about App.EventBus, which module I need to install. Sorry for some stupid questions, cuz I am quite new to Haskell.

Comment: You can use Hayoo! (link in my answer) to find it. But I'm wondering why you're chasing down packages by hand. If whatever code you're trying to build has a `.cabal` file, you can just do `cabal install` in the project directory and it should install all the necessary dependencies for you.

Comment: How can I do that? I have 2 file. File A uses File B. I compile them as follow: ghc FileA.hs FileB.hs     ------> and it still announces error like Could not find App.EventBus

Comment: Like I said, Hayoo! will tell you which package to install.