# Local install packages with Stack for use with runhaskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am developing many small haskell programs that I indent to use as script files. My ideal use-case is to `stack runhaskell one-of-the-scripts.hs` to run them.

Some of the files use dependencies on packages in hackage, such as [regex-posix](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-posix-0.95.2). Therefore I get an error message saying

```
    Could not find module `Text.Regex.Posix'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
2 | import Text.Regex.Posix
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have considered two options:

1. Use a cabal package and specify dependencies therein. I don't like this solution since it (by what I understand) is used in a workflow where I always compile my code. I would like to use `stack runhaskell` instead!
2. Ditch stack and use cabal straight up instead, as suggested in an answer to a  similar question here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13485987/4050510. I dont like this, since I would like to have all my dependencies listed in some file explicitly.

What is the simplest way to install packages from hackage locally, and have then available for `stack runhaskell` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use the script interpreter. Sorry over concision on the answer but I'm on my phone. Here's the docs for it: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#script-interpreter

You could also just do "stack build regex-posix", and then the package will be available to runhaskell. However, this is more error prone because no package hiding is used so it's trickier to tell what the script actually depends on

Comment: The script interpreter is okay for my needs, since it will have all dependencies written out, and so I have dependencies under version control. Nice. Thank you!